# functional dependencies candidate keys

Tags: database, relational-database, functional-dependencies, database-theory

Consider the following relation and the set of functional dependencies (FDs).
R = (A B C D E F G H I)

```
D -> H
DH -> A
EFH -> C
AF -> IG
CD -> ABG
IB -> C
G -> I
IBC->E
F -> H
C -> IE
```

1. Find the candidate key(s) of R.
2. Find the minimal cover of FD set.

I think "DF" is one of candicate keys.

Comment: I find 

`DF-> ADFHGI`

but I couldn't find the relation with B , C and E?

Comment: Doesn't that mean DF isn't a candidate key?

Comment: maybe but I think DF is candidate key but again i can be wrong. Is CDF , BDF and EDF are candidate keys?

Comment: Yes. CDF, BDF, and EDF are candidate keys. That's all of them.

Comment: I found below minimal set is it true?                                                                                               D -> AH ,                                                           EF -> C,
AF -> G ,
CD -> A ,                                                                  CD -> G,
IB -> C,
G -> I,                                                              F -> H
C-> E,
C -> I ,

Comment: I think you're close, but I don't think it's right. You seem to have lost DH->A. (There might be other problems; I stopped after I found the first one.)

Answer (score 0):

The ONLY candidate key is DF.

And the Minimal cover is as follows:

```
D->AH;
EF->C;
AF->G;
CD->ABG;
IB->C;
G->I;
F->H;
C->IE
```